# Android: measured distance between locations is wrong

Tags: android, location, distance

...or most probably, I am doing it wrong. What I want is to display a Toast every one meter I walk inside home. The code below gives me wrong results, as the moment I install the app on my phone I get a Toast without even moving!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private LocationListener mLocationListener;
private String mLocationProvider;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private Location mCurrentLocation;
private int mCounter = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    Criteria criterion = new Criteria();
    criterion.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criterion.setCostAllowed(true);
    criterion.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);

    mLocationProvider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criterion, true);      
}   

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCurrentLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mLocationProvider);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationProvider, 5000, 1, mLocationListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location newlocation) {
        float distance = mCurrentLocation.distanceTo(newlocation);
        if (distance >= 1) {
            mCounter++;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.format("Message #%d: you walked one more meter", mCounter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mCurrentLocation = newlocation;
        }
    }       
}
}
```

Comment: The moment I installed the app the distance variable was set to 3.036. Is this because the provider used is the network and not the gps?

Comment: Yes, Network provider gives unstable results. Your location is continously chnaging.

Comment: Maybe you're right, still though I received misleading results using the gps outside

Comment: You have to understand that 1m accuracy is too less. Be it for gps or Network provider.

Comment: If you take multiple readings in a short period of time (assuming no reflection off objects) and then average the location (probably have to remove outliers) you MAY get a correct location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GPS signal is not precise enough to give exact locations for a 1m radius. There can be deviation peeks up to 50 - 100m in real situations using GPS. This depends much on the environment you are at. GPS will be reflected by buildings, water etc. An average deviation is 10 - 20m. This will get even worse if your inside of a building using a GPS provider instead of a Network provider.

Furthermore you will never get the same coordinates twice in a row, because of this. Even if you don't move! To avoid that you could temporarly save the location and compare it with the new location. If the distance between them hits a defined boarder use the new location.

Answer (score 0):

Change your location provider to GPS. And you have instantiated the LocationListener before you request the new Location(in onResume(); onResume() will be called after onCreate()). This might be the reason for your app showing Toast on start up.. Try to instantiate LocationListener after the requestLocationUpdates()..